# Error when compiling with pdflatex

Tags: errors, compilation-error

`command txs:/// svnadmin creates "C:/users/Manjoy/Desktop?/Boolean algebra/repo" no defined`
After clicking ok, I get
`xs:/// svnadmin creates "C:/users/Manjoy/Desktop?/Boolean algebra/repo/trunk"-m "txs auto generate" no defined`
Frequently I get this notifications following some 5 to 6 notifications like this.

What's happening with this?

I'm using Miktex, version 2.9, Latex editor is Texstudio

Comment: What editor are you using? I'm guessing Vim, and this has something to do with how your version control is set up. But I don't think this has anything to do with TeX, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, in TeX studio, you've set up TeXstudio to use svn for version control but don't have svn installed. Your options are

1. Install an svn version.
2. Go into TeXstudio configuration, select SVN from the left column and make sure that "Automatically check in after save" is not checked. Unless you really want to use svn to manage versions of your file, this is probably the best option.